# Prove or disprove: if $f(n)=O(g^2(n))$ then $2^{f(n)}=O(8^{g(n)})$

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

Prove or disprove:

> if $f(n)=O(g^2(n))$ then $2^{\large f(n)}=O(8^{\large g(n)})$.

If $f(n)=O(g^2(n))$ then we have $2^{\large f}$ and $8^{\large g^2}$. If  we apply $\log$ then we have:
$$
\log 2^f\quad\text{and}\quad\log 8^{\large g^2}=\log 2^{\large 3g^2}\\
\Rightarrow f\quad\text{and}\quad 3g^2
$$
We were given that $f(n)=O(g^2(n)$ therefore $2^{\large f(n)}=O(8^{\large g(n)})$

Comment: With all due respect, you really have to learn how to write proofs or better understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither you proved nor disproved it.

You can see it on a simple counterexample. I suppose it is meant for $n\to\infty$. Consider $g(n)=n$ and $f(n)=n^2$. We get $f\in O(g^2)$ since $f=g^2$. Now we disprove $2^f\in O(8^g)$.
Consider
$$
2^f\in O(8^g)\Leftrightarrow \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{2^{f(n)}}{8^{g(n)}}\right|<\infty.
$$
Now we compute
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n^2}}{8^n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}2^{n^2-3n}=\infty.
$$
This proves $2^f\notin O(8^g)$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(n) = n \cdot \log{n} = O(n^2) \Rightarrow g(n) = n$

Then, as per the relation, $2^{\large n \cdot \log{n}} = O(8^n) = O(2^{\large 3n})$, which is obviously false for all $n \gt 8$.

Comment: The potential problem with your answer is that it doesn't satisfy the starting conditions that is $f\le g^2$ because in your example $f <g^2$ which is a strict inequality. This is why: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{n\log n}=\lim \frac{n}{\log n}=\lim \frac{1}{1/n}=\lim n=\infty$

Comment: @Yos: You mixed something up. If $f<g^2$ then $f\leq g^2$ is true too. And consider $f\in O(g)$ since $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right|=\limsup\frac{n\log n}{n^2}=0<\infty$.

Comment: @Yos That's true, but for $O$ notation the inequality doesn't need to be in a limit in Computer Science. I'm not sure if in Mathematics if it has to be a close bound and higher only in the sense of limits. Is that the case?

Comment: In CS terms it'd be more correct to write $n\log n=o(n^2)$ (little-O). Asymptotically $n\log n\neq n^2$ so it can't be $n\log n=O(n^2)$

Comment: @Yos agreed. However it is common practice to misuse the $O$ notation and in this case helps to bring out a counter-example. I'll try to make something more asymptotically sane.

Comment: @user1952500 you gave a great example, it's just that if I used it in my class in a test I would've probably got points off.